# How do I plot elements of a list?

Tags: python, list, plot

I have imported yahoo data into a list of lists so that each list has all the data for each day.  I want to use the first entry (date entry) of the list for the abscissa.  I have gone through a lot of examples and many use dictionaries which I am unfamiliar with.  I figured something like this:

`chart.plot(data[:][0], data[:][1])`

would work but it doesn't.  Apparently, `data[:][0]` will just give you the first list as opposed to the first element of every list.  I know, I could just make 2 new lists of all the dates and say stock prices with a for loop but that seems wrong.

Comment: how are you getting this data, can you post the URL or what are you using?

Comment: http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=GLD&f=snl1ohgdr  but that isn't relevant.  Basically I want to know if I have a list of lists where each list is [x,y] and want to plot the values can I do it without making 2 new lists of just the x values and y values.

Comment: You should edit the tags of your question to include which language you're using (Python, I'm assuming) and which libraries (matplotlib, pandas, whatever.)

Comment: This is giving a file with a line separated by ",". This is easily separated with any scripting language, such as python, maybe you should rewrite a question asking help with a particular language and putting this request in the question, explaining the format of the results.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed this site was all python.  I am having no difficulties importing the file into an array or performing any of the analysis I need to do, it is just that when I go to plot the results I can't because of what I mentioned above.  Right now all the data is organized in 2 columns and I would have to go back and redo it all into two rows to get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

To get `n`th elements of every list in list, you can use list comprehension:

```
#nth_elements = [l[n] for l in data]
#for example:
x_list = [l[0] for l in data]
y_list = [l[1] for l in data]
```

Now you can call `chart.plot(x_list, y_list)`.

---

If you don't like the "extra" variables, you can use list comprehension directly in the function call:

```
chart.plot([l[0] for l in data], [l[1] for l in data])
```

---

However a simple for loop does the same in one loop, so no need to loop twice over your `data` list:

```
x_list = []
y_list = []
for l in data:
    x_list.append(l[0])
    y_list.append(l[1])
```

Even if it's not that pythonic, it works and is original. It shouldn't feel "wrong" at all.

Answer (score 0):

Does this interest you ? :

```
li = [["GLD","SPDR Gold Trust",
       '161.57','161.47','162.02','161.20','0.00','N/A'],

      ["SLV","iShares Silver Trust",
       '30.29','30.65','25.34','36.44','0.00','N/A'],

      ["GDX","Market Vectors Gold Miners ETF",
       '42.31','42.77','39.08','57.91','0.00','N/A']]

from itertools import izip

for el in zip(*li):
    print el
```

displays

```
('GLD', 'SLV', 'GDX')
('SPDR Gold Trust', 'iShares Silver Trust', 'Market Vectors Gold Miners ETF')
('161.57', '30.29', '42.31')
('161.47', '30.65', '42.77')
('162.02', '25.34', '39.08')
('161.20', '36.44', '57.91')
('0.00', '0.00', '0.00')
('N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A')
```

Comment: @Jon Clements An error in code, should be ``for el in izip(*li)``. izip doesn't build all the data in an object, it creates an iterator .- But my answer is stupid, I think Markus Meskanen's answer is the right one, I will delete mine

Answer (score 0):

`data[:]` only gets all elements of `data` in a list. This is the same as doing `data[1:4]` which gets elements starting from 1 and ending to 4: `[1, 2, 3]`.

To do something *for* every element of the list, you need to use `for` loop.

```
list1, list2 = [], []
for list in data:
    list1.append(list[0])
    list2.append(list[1])
```